# What is the name for someone who offers help, then complains about it?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, popular-refrains

Is there a name for someone who offers help or resources, then complains about it, usually to a third party, but sometimes also to the person who was given the help.

Example: Mary offers to buy Judith a picture frame, for Judith's Children. Mary is then overheard sometime later complaining that it cost $xx to Barbara - Yet she made the offer.

> Mary is such a _____.

Comment: Related: [Politically correct synonym for Indian giver](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255284/politically-correct-synonym-for-indian-giver)

Answer (score 2):

The term *[martyr complex](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Martyr%20Complex)* may apply

> When someone is asked to do something on behalf of a friend, and they agree, but then act like they've made huge sacrifices and should be repaid 100 times more.

*Urban Dictionary*

A bit more can be found at *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr_complex)*

> In psychology a person who has a martyr complex, sometimes associated with the term victim complex, desires the feeling of being a martyr for his/her own sake, seeking out suffering or persecution because it either feeds a psychological need, or a desire to avoid responsibility.

Comment: *Martyr complex* is not a name for the person, however. Informally, people might use the name *martyr* for the person.

Comment: @Drew Good point. The difficulty is that referring to the person as a *martyr* suggests a sacrifice, often of religious overtone, that is not warranted. The person suffering from a martyr complex is self serving, not self sacrificing. The best I can do is a noun phrase, *person with [or suffering from] a martyr complex*.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know of a real (correct/accurate) single-word answer for the question.

Comment: @Drew Maybe we need to coin an idiom, such as [*bad Samaritan*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BadSamaritan)?

Answer (score -1):

Since references to martyrs in the religious sense are infrequent I would go with the term martyr.

Comment: Why do think this? I would say the [*most common*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/martyr) way context of the term is religious. Please expand on your answer, ideally with sources.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Skooba on this. Martyr is almost always seen in a religious context.

Comment: This depends on one's point of view.  I am a non-religious person who has always been interested in psychology.   I use and hear the term martyr in relation to a righteous person who complains about the trouble encountered when being kind to others.   I see how a religious Christian who is knowledgeable about saints might be mostly familiar with religious martyrs.